# ImportError: cannot import name 'app_settings' from 'leaflet'

Tags: python, django, leaflet

I was running django project in Anaconda prompt and I got the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\hp\geoportal_geodjango\mysite\polls\admin.py", line 4, in <module>
    from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\leaflet\admin.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .forms.widgets import LeafletWidget
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\leaflet\forms\widgets.py", line 15, in <module>
    from leaflet import app_settings, PLUGINS, PLUGIN_FORMS
ImportError: cannot import name 'app_settings' from 'leaflet' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\leaflet\__init__.py)
```

I tried different leaflet versions.

Comment: it's an open issue (https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet/issues/259), 

I suggest you Django 2.2 and Python 3.5.(https://travis-ci.org/github/makinacorpus/django-leaflet/jobs/622608647)

Answer (score 4):

just use `pip install django-leaflet==0.19.0` and it will uninstall the Django-leaflet you installed and install v 0.19.0

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have v0.19 installed, uninstall it and the install it again

Comment: this is not an answer, but a good comment. pls, read the rules.